# What object is being returned by .responseXML()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, activexobject

I am trying to create a prototype/class that inherits from the object that is returned by a specific function. But I dont know what that object's *name* is?

For the instance `var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();` what object is returned by `xhr.responseXML;`? Is it `XMLDocument`? Or maybe `XMLDOM`?
Also if I create the object `var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");` and call `xmlDoc.load("xmlFile.xml" );` will it return the same type of object as `xhr.responseXML;`?

I am trying to do the following:

```
function XMLHandler()
{
   this.xmlFile = "defaultXML.xml";
}

// Make XMLHandler inherit from Javascript object
XMLHandler.prototype = new XMLDocument();
XMLHandler.prototype.constructor = XMLDocument;
```

Comment: SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. Separate questions should be, well, separate.

Comment: Please remove your second question and repost it as a real second question by `Ask Question` button on right top.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include unrelated questions in the same post. To address your second question about declaring a function within a "class":

Your first syntax, declaring it within the constructor, will pointlessesly overwrite `myClass.prototype.publicFunct` to point to a newly created function every time the constructor is called. That is, you will be creating an extra copy of the function with each call to the constructor, with `myClass.prototype.publicFunct` always pointing to the most recently created copy - or undefined until the constructor has been called at least once. Don't do this.

Your second option is simply invalid syntax in JavaScript.

**Your third syntax is prefered.** This will add the function to the prototype *once*.

*Remember: JavaScript doesn't have classes as such, though you can sort of simulate them if you think it is worth the bother.*

Answer (score 0):

I can tell by your recent questions that you are thinking like Java, which this is not.

**First question:**
`responseXML` is different for each browser. [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) gives a `nsIDOMDocument`, [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives an `IXMLDOMDocument` and Webkit browsers depend on the [`responseType` setting](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) but will probably be `Document`. Since you cannot predict what it will be stop trying to extend it. In most cases the type isn't made available by the browser's API so javascript cannot extend it anyway.

Moreover, since JavaScript's inheritance is not class based you are forced into doing this:

```
XMLHandler.prototype = new XMLDocument();
```

...which simply does not work for your purpose. Any instance of `XMLHandler` will be built on an unrelated, empty document and not the document returned by `responseXML`. You have to use a wrapper here.

---

**Second Question:**
Of your 3 methods the first is equivalent to the last but more wasteful because it repeatedly sets the same function to the same prototype. The second is nonsensical, the syntax is broken. These are your real options:

```
// Instance method, every instance is given a copy of the function upon "new"
function MyClass()
{
    this.publicFunct = function()
    {
        alert("public function");
    };
}

// Prototypal method, only one copy of the function shared by all instances
function MyClass()
{
}

MyClass.prototype.publicFunct = function()
{
    alert("public function");
};

// Shorthand method, same as prototypal but handy for several members at once
// It prevents MyClass from being a descendent of another type
function MyClass()
{
}

MyClass.prototype = {
    // A colon is only acceptable in object notation
    publicFunct: function()
    {
        alert("public function");
    }
};
```

I would go with a prototypal method for efficiency unless you need to selectively add functions to a class. Your use of "public function" (also "class") seems like another symptom of an OOP background, there aren't any private functions in JavaScript so "public" has no place, all member functions are public. If at some point you do need a private function you can fake the effect with a closure.

```
(function() {

    // Assignments are mostly global
    MyClass = function() {};

    MyClass.prototype.publicFunct = function()
    {
        privateFunct();
    };

    // These statements affect local scope
    var foo = 'bar';

    function privateFunct()
    {
        alert("public function");
    }

})(); // These extra brackets cause the contents to be executed immediately
```

Having said that it is rare to need private functions and all JavaScript is visible anyway so it's not secret really. The above could be thwarted like this:

```
thief = {};
MyClass.prototype.publicFunct.call(thief);
// privateFunct is called by publicFunct in the context of the thief
```

You might as well accept that functions are public. You can go a step further and give up on classes altogether. Objects are just objects that happen to have some functions and those functions can even be shared with completely different objects.

Comment: _"the first is equivalent to the last but more wasteful because it repeatedly sets the same function to the same prototype"_ - it's even more wasteful than that because it's not the _same_ function: it repeatedly creates a new function and assigns it. In your last example about thwarting private functions, the private function _is_ still private - you can't call it directly.